# Use correct dependencies when switching branches in a Python project

Tags: python, git, dependencies

Say I have two branches `a` and `b`. `a` introduces a new dependency which is not used in `b`. When I `git checkout b`, I don't want that dependency installed in my virtualenv. But when I do `git checkout a` I want it installed. Is there a tool which automates this process of keeping a Python virtualenv up to date with the dependencies used by the current branch?

**Note:**

[Switching branches in Git with external dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902264/switching-branches-in-git-with-external-dependencies) addresses this problem with Java and Maven and [How to handle dependancy when switching git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056190/how-to-handle-dependancy-when-switching-git-branches) addresses it with C#. I am asking here specifically about Python.

Answer (score 0):

I see 4 ways to handle this:

1. Install all dependencies and stop worrying about dependencies when switching branches.
2. Delete and recreate the virtualenv on `git checkout`. Do it in a [`post-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) hook to make this completely automatic.
3. Create two virtualenvs and two worktrees, checkout branches `a` and `b` in these worktrees and never switch branches again.
4. Add dependencies to the repository. That way dependencies will be switched automatically with branches.

Comment: My question is how to automate this so that I don't even have to think about it when I check out a branch. Never switching branches is not an option, especially since this will not be limited to only two branches.

Comment: Delete and recreate the virtualenv in a `post-checkout` hook to make this completely automatic.